# How to Call All Modules inside Package?

Tags: python, python-module

I have a project which has this hierarchy

```
tasker/
        table/
                __init__.py
                user.py
                task.py
                ...
        __init__.py
        tasker.py
```

every file inside `table` folder (except `__init__.py`) contains a class that has a same name as the file name except the first letter is capitalized. I want to call and instantiate every class inside `table` folder in `tasker.py`. I can do it by writing

```
import table
```

inside `tasker.py`. But, it turns out that I have to write for example

```
table.user.User()
```

to instantiate class inside `user.py` and it looks very ugly. Is there any way so that I only type at least

```
user.User()
```

or even better,

```
User()
```

to instantiate those classes?

Note: Every files inside `table` folder is dinamically changed. I might add or remove file in `table` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing most of the work automatically. You can register your modules of interest in `tasker.table.__init__`:

```
table_registry = ['user', 'task', ...]
```

You don't need to import anything at this point and I wouldn't recommend using `__all__` as it serves a different purpose altogether. The advantage of using a manually created list is that your package can contain other modules without any interference.

Now `tasker.tasker` can do all the work dynamically:

```
from .table import table_registry
from importlib import import_module

pkg = 'tasker.table'
for name in table_registry:
    mod = import_module('.' + name, package=pkg)
    name = name.titlecase()
    # Check if module contains uppercased class name
    if hasattr(mod, name):
        cls = getattr(mod, name)
        # Check if it's a class
        if isinstance(cls, type):
            # Assign to current module
            globals()[name] = cls

del name, mod, cls
```

If you don't want to bother with manually registering your modules of interest, you can dynamically discover them using the utilities in [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html). In This version, `tasker.table.__init__` can remain empty. `tasker.tasker` will get the module list like this:

```
from pkgutil import walk_packages
from importlib import import_module

for info in walk_packages(tasker.table.__path__, prefix='tasker.table.'):
    if info.ispkg: continue
    mod = import_module(info.name)
    name = info.name.split('.')[-1].titlecase()
    if hasattr(mod, name):
        ...
```

The remainder of the code is the same as for the manual version. This version will recurse into any sub-packages it finds. It will work fine as long as you don't do anything crazy with your `__path__` attributes.

Comment: @abdul_niyas_pm. Your answer wasn't that bad. There was no need to delete it.

Comment: I don't understand part `globals()[name] = cls()`. Is that putting an instance of class inside a variable? Is that mean variable `User` is already an instance and not a class? Because I want to instantiate class multiple times inside `tasker.tasker`. Is it okay if I write `globals()[name] = cls` instead?

Comment: @fahadh4ilyas. Yes of course. I misunderstood your requirement

Comment: I've tried it and it's working. But, it's kind of slow when I do `from tasker.tasker import something`. Is it because for loop?

Comment: That being said, Python will only run that loop once. The first import from tasker may be slow, but the second and following shouldn't be.

Comment: Yeah, I decide to only write `import_module('.' + name, package=pkg)` inside that for loop because probably there would be multiple classes inside every module. Is that okay or I did it wrong?

Comment: @fahadh4ilyas. Whether you import one name from the module or the whole thing, the whole thing gets imported and added to `sys.modules`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
from table import user

user.User()
```

Comment: It's working but I have to manually write `from table import module`. Is there any way to do it dinamically?

Answer (score 0):

you can import all modules inside a package at once using asterisks:

```
from table import *
```